# React ignore some child elements on initial clientside render/hydrate

Tags: reactjs

So I've got a multipage isomorphic React 16 app and I'm looking for a way to have the client-side hydrating and mounting completely ignore certain DIVs.

Reason is that after the server sends the initial HTML but before React bootstraps itself on the client I'm making DOM changes that I want to keep.

Specifically, there's a back-and-forth flow that involves going from an infinite scrolling list view to a detail view and back to the list view, and to make "back" snappy I'm storing a big chunk of the page HTML in sessionStorage on the client. Then an inline chunk of script simply says something like

```
if (window.performance.navigation.type == 2) {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = sessionStorage.get('cacheHtml');`
}
```

Why not do this in `componentDidMount`? It's noticeably quicker to do it before React even runs. HTML is restored so quick it's perceived as basically instantaneous. If I wait for React lifecycle events it's quite a bit laggier.

Why not use `componentShouldUpdate`? That only tells React not to re-render on changes, it doesn't prevent the initial reconciliation.

As things stand it does work, it just gives me a warning in development about unexpected DIVs.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Just asking to ask : `It's noticeably quicker to do it before React even runs. HTML is restored so quick it's perceived as basically instantaneous.` -> Are you only running and testing this in development mode, or have you tested this in a 'Production' state?